anonymous class in C++
In Java/Kotlin im used to do this:
interface MyInterface {
   fun run();
}

And then creating anonymous instances like so:
val actions = arrayOf(
  object: MyInterface {
     fun run(){
       //do something
     }
  },
  object: MyInterface {
     fun run(){
       //do something
     }
  }
);

Id like to do something similar in C++ :
class MyClass {
   virtual void run();
}


MyClass actions[10] = {
   new MyClass(){
      void run() {
       // something 
      }
   }
}

Is this possible?

std::function and array using lambda might be what you really want.

can you expand you answer please

Don't you have access to functional interfaces there? Kotlin (and modern Java) allow you to convert a lambda into an anonymous single-method interface implementation. In c++ you would also use a lambda, possibly in combination with std::function.

Minimal example: std::array<std::function<void()>, 2> actions = { []{ /* something */ }, []{ /* something */ } };. Live demo: https://godbolt.org/z/xdjMY7dc7.

struct Base{}; struct Foo { struct:Base{} derived_member; }; struct:Base {} derived_variable;

You might want to have a list of "executor":
std::vector<std::function<void()>> funcs = {
   [](){ std::cout << "First function\n"; },
   [](){ std::cout << "Second function\n"; },
   // ...
};

Else, C++ allows to declare anonymous classes in some scope when declaring variable, but seems not suitable for your array need:
struct MyInterface {
   virtual ~MyInterface() = default;
   virtual void run() = 0;
};


void foo()
{
    struct : MyInterface {
        void run() override { std::cout << "s1\n"; }
    } s1;
    struct : MyInterface {
        void run() override { std::cout << "s2\n"; }
    } s2;
    MyInterface* interfaces[] = {&s1, &s2};

    for (auto* o : interfaces) {
        o->run();
    }
}

Demo

Curiously, with MingW as installed on my windows box (and turning foo() into a main()) your second example fails to link, with an error message from the linker about being unable to find the vtable for MyInterface.   The workaround [which I confess I fail to understand] for that was for MyInterface::run() to be pure virtual.

Common implementations place vtable inside the TU implementing the first non pure virtual function, ignoring destructor or taking other strategy might explain why compiler expect vtable in TU where MyInterface ::run is implemented (and there was none). Fixed on my side too to add the missing = 0.

C++ does not have a complete real equivalent to Java's anonymous class.
However - if your interface contains one method, you can use std::function with lambdas to achieve what you need:
#include <functional>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using MyInterfaceFunc = std::function<void(void)>;

int main() {
    // Vector of lambdas which are converatble to `MyInterfaceFunc`:
    std::vector<MyInterfaceFunc> actions = {
        [](){ std::cout << "do something 1\n"; },
        [](){ std::cout << "do something 2\n"; },
    };

    // ...

    // Execute the actions:
    for (auto & action : actions ) {
        action();
    }
}

Output:
do something 1
do something 2

Live demo

ok followup question does this allow you to have fields in MyInterfaceFunc as well?

Not as such. But you can make the function accept parameters, and you can also add captures to the lambda to mimik some state.

Captures are data members, but operator() is const by default, so mutating them requires marking the lambda mutable

since C++23 the recommended way is std::move_only_function

@AhmedAEK that depends if you want something copyable or not
